# Mobile site in webview doesn't work

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-webview, user-agent

Well i'm working for a simple webview to display a website of course..this website has a mobile version but when i try to run the application the webview displays the desktop mode. I tryied every way but nothing seems to work.. I tryied to change the user agent but nothing..
This is the part of user agent i'm using now

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U;`
Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like
Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
```

Of course doesn't work.

Another one (doesn't work)

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.2; Nexus 7Build/JRO03D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Safari/535.19");
```

And many others but none works. What can i do?

EDIT with my code

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS); // Request     progress circle
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings websettings = webview.getSettings();
        websettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en)AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); // Show progress circle

        final Activity activity = this;

        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                    activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                    activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                    if(progress == 100)
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false); // Hide progress circle when page loaded
                    activity.setTitle("Title");
                }
            });
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            webview.loadUrl("http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Following Snippet hope this will work with you

```
 webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en)AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");
```

Comment: Not work..i edited the question with the whole code so you can see better

Comment: replace the string and the Try 
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-us; Nexus One Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1

Comment: if i write `webview.loadUrl("http://forum.ubuntu-it.org/index.php?mobile=on");` the first page starts correctly in mobile version.. But when i try navigate and click in some link it ask if i want open it with a browser (stock browser, dolphin, chrome). Or the second page loads in normal mode and not mobile..

Answer (score 0):

> [...] when i try to run the application the webview displays the desktop
>   mode.. [...] I tryied to change the user agent but nothing..

Try to **remove** "webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(.. "..

Android open in "mobile mode" by default..

> [...] when i try navigate and click in some link it ask if i want open
>   it with a browser.

To open links clicked by the user **inside** your WebView, simply provide a WebViewClient for your WebView, using setWebViewClient(). For example:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html